# Empty list vs Maybe to represent failed computation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

Over at the [Edx Haskell course](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-functional-programming-delftx-fp101x), Erik Meijer repeatedly states that using the `Maybe` type for failed computations is not something one should do; instead, one should use the empty list for that.

My understanding is that the `Maybe` type is a good thing and that we should use it. However, it seems that a list can model everything a `Maybe` can model and more... So why do we need the `Maybe` type at all?

Comment: An example speaks a thousand words. Also, a link to the course you mention would be great.

Comment: @Jubobs: Probably: https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-functional-programming-delftx-fp101x.

Comment: @Zeta Sure, but the onus to add the link is on the OP :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list can model an arbitrary number of results. On the other hand, `Maybe` models exactly *one* result or *no result at all*.

Think about the following functions:

```
f1 :: A -> [B]
f2 :: B -> [C]
f3 :: C -> [D]
f4 :: D -> [E]
```

It's not clear how many elements `f1`, `f2`, `f3` or `f4` return. So what happens if you sequence them?

```
f  :: A -> [E]
f s = f1 s >>= f2 >>= f3 >>= f4
```

How many elements should the result contain? One? Zero? Did we accidentally create a list with n^n (n ~ input length) elements?

However, if the computations are going to return exactly one value or no value at all, the proper type gives us all the necessary information right away:

```
f1 :: A -> Maybe B
f2 :: B -> Maybe C
f3 :: C -> Maybe D
f4 :: D -> Maybe E

f  :: A -> Maybe E
f s = f1 s >>= f2 >>= f3 >>= f4
```

So that's that. Now back to Meijer's statement:

> Erik Meijer repeatedly states that using the Maybe type for failed computations is not something one should do; instead, one should use the empty list for that.

Without any additional objective reasoning, this is just a personal preference. I could tell everyone that `fmap` is better than `map`, it's something we should do. And at that point, you either believe me, or you ask questions. If he didn't make it clear in his lecture, ask him directly.

Answer (score 17):

> However it seems that a list can model everything a Maybe can model and more

The "and more" is an excellent reason to use `Maybe`. As a consumer of a list, you need to be able to handle zero, one or multiple values. As a consumer of a `Maybe`, you only need to be able to handle zero or one values. So in cases where multiple values don't make sense, it is much better to use `Maybe` so that you know statically that you won't get nonsensical values.

Comment: A list is an excellent choice for computations that are só wildly successful that they return more than one value :-)

Answer (score 1):

In favor of lists:

- The extra values are not a problem. The client can always choose to ignore the rest of the list when there is more than one result.
- Using only lists avoids tedious conversions between Maybe and lists when we have to mix both. No need for `listToMaybe` or `maybeToList`.
- [`catMaybes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) becomes just `concat` (or `join`).

One possible concern is that repeated uses of `(>>=)` for the list monad can create really big lists. However, Haskell is lazy. If we only ever use the first element, the rest of the list won't be computed.

```
>>> head (let xs = [1..1000000] in xs >>= \_ -> xs >>= \_ -> xs)
1
```

Comment: That's a good point I hadn't thought of. However as someone using a function that takes a list, I think I'd be a bit surprised if it threw away the tail. For example imagine if `map` was implemented as `map f [] = [] ; map f (x:xs) = [f x]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I would join the choir here saying that I can't evaluate Meijer's recommendation unless I was presented with all of the details of his argument for it.  To me it seems simple:

1. Use `Maybe` for functions that return 0 or 1 results.
2. Use `[]` for functions that return 0 or more results.
3. If you need to mix and match between functions that make different choices, one option is to use functions like `listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a` and `maybeToList :: Maybe a -> [a]` from [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Maybe.html) to adapt functions written in one style to work in the other.
4. If you want to delay the choice of whether to use `Maybe` or `[]`, you can use the `Alternative` or `MonadPlus` classes.

Example of point #4:

```
import Control.Applicative (pure, Alternative(..))

safeDiv :: (Alternative f, Fractional a, Eq a) => a -> a -> f a
safeDiv _ 0 = empty
safeDiv x y = pure (x / y)

{-

>>> safeDiv 5 2 :: Maybe Float
Just 2.5

>>> safeDiv 5 0 :: Maybe Float
Nothing

>>> safeDiv 5 2 :: [Float]
[2.5]

>>> safeDiv 5 0 :: [Float]
[]

-}

bothSqrt :: (Alternative f, Floating a) => a -> f a
bothSqrt x = let x' = sqrt x
             in pure x' <|> pure (-x')

{-

>>> bothSqrt 5 :: Maybe Float
Just 2.236068

>>> bothSqrt 5 :: [Float]
[2.236068,-2.236068]

>>> bothSqrt 5 >>= flip safeDiv 2 :: Maybe Float
Just 1.118034

>>>> bothSqrt 5 >>= flip safeDiv 2 :: [Float]
[1.118034,-1.118034]

-}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another valuable point of Maybe is that it is just the simplest case of error-handling monads, which can be used to represent and compose „breakable“ computations in a convenient and consistent way (another examples are Either and pure exceptions). The list monad is semantically different (it represents non-deterministic computations) and has a similar behaviour only in the empty/singleton case, as it was shown above.